# Setting authentication option in devise according to user's choice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap

I have two type of devise authentication in my Rails App. One is LDAP and another one is Database authentication. I want to make it according to user options. I tried some of the things of making that option as function and pass the value. But its showing me error:`uninitialized constant Devise::Models::Authentication (NameError)`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :authentication, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  def authentication
    flag=1
    if flag == true
        auth = "database_authenticatable"
    else
        auth = "ldap_authenticatable"
    end
    "#{auth}"
  end
end
```

Right now i want to make this code work after that i will add the option of flag on my own. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  if flag == 1
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
  else
    devise :ldap_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
  end
end`

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
devise *devise_options

def devise_options
  [:authentication, 
  :registerable, 
  :recoverable, 
  :rememberable, 
  :trackable, 
  :validatable, 
  (flag ? :database_authenticatable : :ldap_authenticatable)]
end
```

Comment: I am getting error in  this line `devise *devise_options` error: `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `devise_options`